# How to prevent deleting of other people's items?

Tags: permissions

Users with "Contribute" permissions are able to delete any item on the list. How can I limit them to delete only the ones that they've created?

Note: "Create items and edit items that were created by the user" is checked in the Item-level Permissions settings group.

Comment: That is what Contribute is for. However, you may need to create a new permission group or change the Contribute permission for the site. You could create a group that has all the levels except delete and make it a limited contribute group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a permission to delete own items. What you could do is remove the delete rights of contributer (or give them other rights on the list), create a workflow (started manually). First you check if the user that created the listitem = current user, if so, delete the listitem. You can hide the delete-button with javascript/jquery

Otherwise, create an eventhandler on the list where you check if the current user is the creator of the listitem. If not, cancel the deletion and show message to user

Comment: That would work for me, but I'm afraid the business would want to click on the Delete Item link. Maybe hiding that button according to some Javascript work could make it?

Comment: Yes, you could do that